# Font Size 72 screwed up Studio

Tags: fonts, bug-reporting, android-studio

New user here.

I dowloaded Android Studio today and finished installation and opened the window `"Welcome to Android Studio"`. I configured my theme and scrolled down to the part where it lets me set my IDE font size. I was playing around with settings and yes, it was stupid, but I accidentally hit font size **72.0**, and now my whole screen (within the *Android Studio* window) seems extremely zoomed in thanks to the enlarged font.

I can't scroll around on the screen, so I can't navigate back to the part where it lets me change my IDE font size in the GUI. I can't find any option to change font size in any of the program files.

I decided to uninstall the studio, and reinstall it, but there are some stored config files that remember the font settings from before. I `cd`-ed into `.config` and used `ls` to list all the directories but didn't see one for Android Studio. I found some Android files in modules that are likely saving the settings but those are uneditable, even after using `chmod +x`.

I'm using Linux Kubuntu, and am a bit of a noob and as such need help and appreciate detailed instructions. Ideas?

Comment: You've provided no release details; and only provide *generic* details as to what you did. When you *uninstall* a package you have the option to remove or keep configs; you don't mention which you tried (*the implication is you didn't purge & appear to be complaining about it*). Why not just modify the file out (*if I make a change & its not good; I'll look for config files that changed at the approx date/time when I made the change as to what files I need to edit for example*).

Comment: You've tagged *bug-reporting*, however this isn't a bug tracker but a user support site..  I'll provide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs for reporting bugs, which applies to all *flavors* of Ubuntu too (but if using 3rd party software, different bug trackers maybe used by that 3rd party project)

Comment: @guiverc sorry I wasn't more specific. I used the purge command, if that's what you mean by purging, and the issue still persisted when I reinstalled it. I looked at all Android Studio config files (here: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config), which were modified around the time of installation like you said, before posting this question, but couldn't find anything fixing the issue, which is why I asked the question.