# Font Size 72 screwed up Android Studio

Tags: kubuntu, fonts, android, android-studio

New user here. Reposting this question as I realize people may have thought I was trolling (I assure I'm not, just a genuinely stupid mistake that I don't know how to fix).

I dowloaded Android Studio today and finished installation and opened the window "Welcome to Android Studio". I configured my theme and scrolled down to the part where it lets me set my IDE font size. I was playing around with settings and yes, it was stupid, but I accidentally hit font size 72.0, and now my whole screen (within the Android Studio window) seems extremely zoomed in thanks to the enlarged font.

I can't scroll around on the screen, so I can't navigate back to the part where it lets me change my IDE font size in the GUI. I can't find any option to change font size in any of the program files.

I decided to uninstall the studio, and reinstall it, but there are some stored config files that remember the font settings from before. I cd-ed into .config and used ls to list all the directories but didn't see one for Android Studio. I found some Android files in modules that are likely saving the settings but those are uneditable, even after using chmod +x.

I'm using Linux Kubuntu, and am a bit of a noob and as such need help and appreciate detailed instructions. Ideas?

Comment: Duplicate of [Font Size 72 screwed up Studio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1498400/font-size-72-screwed-up-studio)

Comment: Please don't post the exact same question twice. If you have new info, edit it into the original question.

Comment: What do I do if no one is answering my question?

Comment: There may be a chance that no one here, or that someone that might know just simply hasn't stopped by.  If you have something more to add to your original question, you can modify your question.  I don't run Android Studio, but https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config shows where the locations of the config file can be.  I have a feeling that when you removed it and reinstalled it, it did not remove and replace the config file.

Comment: Phew, I fixed it. It wasn't in any of the stated config files in the studio wiki, but I found it in a file in my snap directory called `other.xml`.